# Why isn't my control updating with my static property?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've gone through some past answers on this and am binding to the static property the same way they prescribe, as far as I can tell. My binding is properly obtaining the value but it's just not updating when that property get's changed. Here is my code:

My class where I define the variable:

```
  public static class Globals
    { 
        private static string file_name;
        
        public static string FILE_NAME
        {
            get { return file_name; }
            set
            {
                file_name = value;
                OnStaticPropertyChanged(nameof(FILE_NAME));
            }
        }
        public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;
        private static void OnStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

The applicable XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="CADViewer.Pages.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CADViewer"
      xmlns:s="clr-namespace:CADViewer"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"  d:DesignWidth="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}"
      Title="MainPage" Background="#282D33">

    <Grid>
       <Label Content="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Globals.FILE_NAME}, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="20" Margin="20, 20, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. This is driving me nuts.

I tried via the means shown above. This was according to previous questions on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this binding which includes a path:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=(local:Globals.FILE_NAME), Mode=OneWay}" 
       FontSize="20" Margin="20, 20, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

You can update the `Label` by setting the static property to a new value:

```
Globals.FILE_NAME = "new value...";
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed my binding from:

```
Content="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Globals.FILE_NAME}, Mode=OneWay}"
```

to:

```
Content="{Binding Path=(local:Globals.FILE_NAME), Mode=OneWay}"
```

and that did it for me.